# How to check in C# if a specific word or another specific word exists in a text using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text lets say "Hi, My name is Ahmad."

How can I make a regular expression that searches for this text for the word "my" and if not found the word"is."
I know how to make a regular expression to search for one word, can I make
one regex that searches for multiple words and stops are the first occurrence?

Comment: Yo are asking two different questions: find "is" if "my" is not found; find the first occurrence of "my" or "is" - which is it?

Comment: From what I understand it seems "look for 'my', and if not found, then look for 'is'".

Comment: `if (myString.Contains("my") { // do something with 'my' string } else if (myString.Contains("is") { // do something with 'is' string }`

Answer (score 0):

You want a reference to the first (of possibly multiple) matches, correct?

1) Q: Why don't you show us what you've tried so far?

2) If you've already got a regex that searches for multiple words ... and if the words are different ... then isn't that equivalent?

3) Finally, if something besides a regex satisfies your goal ... then why insist on a regex?  For example:

```
int i;
if ((i = s.indexOf("my")) >= 0 || (i = s.indexOf("s")) >= 0) {
  System.out.println("i=" + i);
}
```

Comment: What does your 3) code does? From what I understand it gives the index of "s" if it's present, else index of "my" if it's present, and if neither is present, nothing? I'm genuinely trying to understand how this works.

Comment: @RufusL yes but if you converted that to C#, would wouldn't it do what I said? I fail to see how that will help in this situation.

Comment: @Sach, `IndexOf` returns the first index of the specified string, or -1 if it's not found. So this code basically looks for "my" or "s", and if either are found, then it writes the index that was returned.

Comment: I see, so if "my" was found it would return the index of "my", and if it wasn't found but "is" (I'm guessing "s" in his code is a typo) is found, then you'd return index of "is". Failing both, return -1. OK so I guess there's no way of finding out index of which was found here if it was.

Comment: you would use an `else if` and split it out into two checks. see my comment in your question.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to use |

```
var match = Regex.IsMatch("Hi, My name is Ahmad", "my|is")
```

The example I gave, however, will also match something like "His name isn't Ahmad." It's not clear if you would want that to match or not.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use the pipe operator '|' so it would be
Regex r= new regex("my|is");